# Test Code coverage for LightningLoginFormController

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

The prebuilt class LightningLoginFormController has a try/catch block that I am trying to cover in test.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String login(String username, String password, String startUrl) {
    try{
        ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
        aura.redirect(lgn);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();            
    }
}
```

I am having trouble getting the login to throw an exception. My current test code is:

```
     try {
  String newRes = LightningLoginFormController.login(null, null, null);
         system.debug('New Result is ' +newRes);
     } catch (DmlException ex) {
            System.assertEquals('expected text', ex.getMessage());
        }  

 }
```

But all it does is return null. Any ideas on how I get the Login method to throw an exception?

My new code, based on @Adrian Larson suggestion is now as follows:

**Class**

```
global class LightningLoginFormController {

<… other code that is already covered …>

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String login(String username, String password, String startUrl) {
        try{
            ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
            aura.redirect(lgn);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }
    }

    
    static LoginService service = new LoginService();
    @TestVisible static void setMock(LoginService mock) { service = mock; }
    public virtual class LoginService
    {
        protected virtual ApexPages.PageReference login(String username, String password, String startUrl)
        {
            return Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@IsTest
public without sharing class LightningLoginFormControllerTest {

 <… other code that already works …>
    
    @IsTest static void testLogin()
    {
        LightningLoginFormController.setMock(new MyMock());
        
        Test.startTest();
        LightningLoginFormController.login('testUser', 'fakepwd', null);
        Test.stopTest();
        
    system.assertEquals(null, 'Exception',
        'The exception should be caught');
    }
    class MyMock extends LightningLoginFormController.LoginService
    {
        protected override ApexPages.PageReference login
            (String username, String password, String startUrl)
        {
            throw new DmlException();
        }
     }
}
```

The problem is the Catch block is still not getting caught and some of the additional code (the public virtual class LoginService method) is not being caught either.

Comment: this Success page has a suggestion: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IJcrQAG

Comment: Thanks. But the only part of the test code that deals with the login method still just gives me a null response instead of actually throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great example of how dependency injection can help you out with testing. You have a dependency (`Site.login`) which you want to express greater control over. Rather than work within its constraints, you can sidestep them by injecting a different behavior. The basic syntax would be to add the following lines to your controller.

```
static LoginService service = new LoginService();
@TestVisible static void setMock(LoginService mock) { service = mock; }
public virtual class LoginService
{
    protected virtual ApexPages.PageReference login(String username, String password, String startUrl)
    {
        return Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
    }
}
```

Make sure you update your controller to swap to this dependency instead (therefore allowing injection).

```
ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl); // before
ApexPages.PageReference loginResult = service.login(username, password, startUrl); // after
```

Then, in your test, you can simply define an extension of this service that instead throws your desired error. Please note that your current assertion structure is deeply flawed, as if you never throw any error you don't even assert anything.

```
@IsTest static void testLogin()
{
    MyController.setMock(new MyMock());
    
    Test.startTest();
        MyController.login(...);
    Test.stopTest();
    
    system.assertEquals(null, expectedException,
        'The exception should be caught');
}
class MyMock extends MyController.LoginService
{
    protected override ApexPages.PageReference login
        (String username, String password, String startUrl)
    {
        throw new DmlException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @cropredy has been trying to get me to learn more about dependency injections. And I swear I am trying but I have a long way to go.

I added what you suggested (or at least my understanding of what you suggested) to my original post. I am still not getting the catch block covered, and now the public virtual class LoginService is not covered either. Did I misinterpret how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: Jonathan - your line `ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);` needs to be `ApexPages.PageReference lgn = service.login(username, password, startUrl);`

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.

Comment: Adrian, I updated your answer with the bit Cropredy added. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Quick question, cropredy, for the code you had me change do I need to create to versions of it - one to run if the user is test and one not? Something like:

            if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                ApexPages.PageReference lgn = service.login(username, password, startUrl);
            } else {
                ApexPages.PageReference lgn = site.login(username, password, startUrl);
            }
            aura.redirect(lgn);
            return null;

Comment: Absolutely not. The whole point of the pattern is that you call `setMock` to change behavior. You have control over how it behaves. `Test.isRunningTest()` takes that away from you.

Comment: Adrian, it took me a while but I got there in the end. This is the point of swapping  the dependency and using the override. Thanks again for the lesson.